# Civilization IV Complete won't run

Tags: civilization-4

I installed Civilization IV after buying the disk from a thrift shop and it installed successfully, along with GameSpy Comrade. I scanned in GameSpy Comrade, after signing up for an account with them, for installed games. I ran the scan several times, but each time it said that no games were installed. When I put the disk back in, and pressed play, it also did nothing. Help?!?

Comment: I've played Civ IV before and I don't remember having to use GameSpy, at least with the single player. Is there any way to play the game without Gamespy? If not, check your Program Files folders to make sure the game is there.

Comment: @Studoku It seemed to have not actually installed the game, although it says it did, and the game won't run if I try running it directly from the disk. GameSpy was optional, and I chose it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: It might just be something like that the CD Key is already taken or something because it's from a thrift shop but I don't know.

Comment: @Studoku It's not in Program Files, but when I put in the CD it won't let me install it, it only has a "Play" option.

Comment: Check Program Files (x86) too. If it's not there either, look for an uninstall option and uninstall and reinstall the game- it might just be a dodgy installation. It's probably not the CD key- Civ IV's CD key doesn't need to be registered.

Comment: What operating system are you using btw?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10779/discussion-between-studoku-and-tater-tot)

Comment: I found out it was actually because of a parental controls option that my parents had on, even though the game was rated E10+, because windows apparently thinks that certain game descriptors are above T (the setting) and it was blocking the game.

Answer (score -6):

You can try re-installing the game.